# Как с помощью js заменить новую строку на символ?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть `<textarea>` Я из неё получаю данные с помощью `$('#head_s').val()` и отправляю по ajax. Проблема в том, что ajax перенос строки превращает в обычный пробел и в php я никак не могу отличить его.

Comment: а Вы уверены, что там есть символ[ы] переноса строки?

Comment: Как Вы отправляете? Символы просто так не заменяются.

Comment: Переносы строки там есть, просто браузер не переносит строку по \n.

Comment: Отправляю с помощью $.ajax('save&text='+$('#head_s').val());, в php заменяю /n \n /r \r на | , но не работает

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте на стороне сервера использовать функцию [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Это php фукция а мне надо js